# Give a formula for the coefficient of $x^{k}$ in the expansion of $(x+{1 \over x})^n$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I followed the binomial theorem and got this:

The Binomial Theorem is: $(a+b)^{n}= \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}{a}^{k}{b}^{n-k}$

Then let $a=x, b={1\over x}, n = n, k = k.$

I then get $\sum_{j=0}^{n}{n \choose j}{x}^{j}{1 \over x}^{n-j}$

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Write $\frac{1}{x} = x^{-1}$ to simplify the expression.

Comment: I'll edit it now.

Comment: Change the index of the sum to some other variable say $j$, instead of $k$.

Comment: Now the power of $x$ in a general term is given by $2j-n$. You want a $j$ such that $2j-n=k$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
  \left( x+\frac{1}{x} \right)^{n}
    &= x^{-n}\left( x^{2}+1 \right)^{n} \\
    &= x^{-n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j} x^{2j} \\
    &= \sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j} x^{2j-n}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  k &= 2j-n \\
  c_{k} &= \frac{1+(-1)^{n+k}}{2} \binom{n}{\frac{n+k}{2}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. You see $$(x+\tfrac 1x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}{x}^{k}{1 \over x}^{n-k}$$ Since $\frac 1x=x^{-1}$ we have $$(x+\tfrac 1x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}{x}^{k}x^{k-n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}{x}^{2k-n}$$
So if we wish to find the coefficient $a_i$ for $x^i$, then $a_i=0$ if $i\not\equiv n \mod 2$ and $a_i={n\choose \frac 12 (i+n)}$ otherwise.